# Android database insert row

Tags: android, sqlite

I have written dynamic insert part.When I excute he Insert statement into sqlite browser , its inserting fine.If do throuh code there are some issues:

This is my code:

```
  public void insertTableRecord(String strTableName, String strToFields, String strValues){
    DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(DownlaodTableActivity.this);
    dbAdapter.openDataBase();

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(strToFields,strValues);
    long n = dbAdapter.insertRecordsInDB(strTableName, null, initialValues);
    System.out.println( " -- inserted status : --- " + n);
}
```

sql statement is :

```
        INSERT INTO  WMTransactionControl(ExecutiveCode,FreeIssuePrefix,DisPaySchedulePrefix,NextFreeIssueNo,NextReturnNo,UploadedType,DisNextFreeIssueNo,DisNextFOCNo,NextVisitNo,DisNextOrderNo,UploadedOn,NextReturnAcceptNo,BusinessUnit,TXNReferencePrefix,OrderPrefix,UploadedMethod,FOCPrefix,ReturnPrefix,RetailerPrefix,NextRetailerNo,NextInvoiceNo,NextGRNNo,InvoicePrefix,NextTXNReference,NextOrderNo,ReturnAcceptPrefix,PaySchedulePrefix,NextReceiptNo,NextFOCNo,NextPayScheduleNo,NextGRONo,DisReturnPrefix,DisReceiptPrefix,DisNextReturnNo,DisOrderPrefix,DisNextReceiptNo,DisNextPayScheduleNo,NextActivityNo,DisInvoicePrefix,DisNextInvoiceNo,UploadedBy,DisFreeIssuePrefix,DisFOCPrefix,ReceiptPrefix) VALUES("WAT2 "," ","","1","20","1","1","1","15","1","Jun 17 2011 6:33PM","1","HEMA","20110708 ","OR4 ","3"," ","RT4 ","TEM4","10","1","1","IN4 ","2","37"," ","PS4","1","20","41","1"," "," ","1"," ","1","1","1"," ","1","WAT2"," "," ","RP4 ");
```

This is sql statement i ran through sqlite browser. its ok.
but code
Error saying like this :

```
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304): Error inserting  ExecutiveCode,FreeIssuePrefix,DisPaySchedulePrefix,NextFreeIssueNo,NextReturnNo,UploadedType,DisNextFreeIssueNo,DisNextFOCNo,NextVisitNo,DisNextOrderNo,UploadedOn,NextReturnAcceptNo,BusinessUnit,TXNReferencePrefix,OrderPrefix,UploadedMethod,FOCPrefix,ReturnPrefix,RetailerPrefix,NextRetailerNo,NextInvoiceNo,NextGRNNo,InvoicePrefix,NextTXNReference,NextOrderNo,ReturnAcceptPrefix,PaySchedulePrefix,NextReceiptNo,NextFOCNo,NextPayScheduleNo,NextGRONo,DisReturnPrefix,DisReceiptPrefix,DisNextReturnNo,DisOrderPrefix,DisNextReceiptNo,DisNextPayScheduleNo,NextActivityNo,DisInvoicePrefix,DisNextInvoiceNo,UploadedBy,DisFreeIssuePrefix,DisFOCPrefix,ReceiptPrefix="WAT2 "," ","","1","20","1","1","1","15","1","Jun 17 2011 6:33PM","1","HEMA","20110708 ","OR4 ","3"," ","RT4 ","TEM4","10","1","1","IN4 ","2","37"," ","PS4","1","20","41","1"," "," ","1"," ","1","1","1"," ","1","WAT2"," "," ","RP4 "
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 1 values for 44 columns: , while compiling: INSERT INTO WMTransactionControl(ExecutiveCode,FreeIssuePrefix,DisPaySchedulePrefix,NextFreeIssueNo,NextReturnNo,UploadedType,DisNextFreeIssueNo,DisNextFOCNo,NextVisitNo,DisNextOrderNo,UploadedOn,NextReturnAcceptNo,BusinessUnit,TXNReferencePrefix,OrderPrefix,UploadedMethod,FOCPrefix,ReturnPrefix,RetailerPrefix,NextRetailerNo,NextInvoiceNo,NextGRNNo,InvoicePrefix,NextTXNReference,NextOrderNo,ReturnAcceptPrefix,PaySchedulePrefix,NextReceiptNo,NextFOCNo,NextPayScheduleNo,NextGRONo,DisReturnPrefix,DisReceiptPrefix,DisNextReturnNo,DisOrderPrefix,DisNextReceiptNo,DisNextPayScheduleNo,NextActivityNo,DisInvoicePrefix,DisNextInvoiceNo,UploadedBy,DisFreeIssuePrefix,DisFOCPrefix,ReceiptPrefix) VALUES(?);
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at com.xont.db.DBAdapter.insertRecordsInDB(DBAdapter.java:214)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at com.xont.controller.DownlaodTableActivity.insertTableRecord(DownlaodTableActivity.java:325)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at com.xont.controller.DownlaodTableActivity.loadDownloadData(DownlaodTableActivity.java:264)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at com.xont.controller.DownlaodTableActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(DownlaodTableActivity.java:204)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2195)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:730)
      08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    08-02 12:25:35.447: ERROR/Database(304):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

strToFields = ExecutiveCode,FreeIssuePrefix,DisPaySchedulePrefix,NextFreeIssueNo,NextReturnNo,UploadedType,DisNextFreeIssueNo,DisNextFOCNo,NextVisitNo,DisNextOrderNo,UploadedOn,NextReturnAcceptNo,BusinessUnit,TXNReferencePrefix,OrderPrefix,UploadedMethod,FOCPrefix,ReturnPrefix,RetailerPrefix,NextRetailerNo,NextInvoiceNo,NextGRNNo,InvoicePrefix,NextTXNReference,NextOrderNo,ReturnAcceptPrefix,PaySchedulePrefix,NextReceiptNo,NextFOCNo,NextPayScheduleNo,NextGRONo,DisReturnPrefix,DisReceiptPrefix,DisNextReturnNo,DisOrderPrefix,DisNextReceiptNo,DisNextPayScheduleNo,NextActivityNo,DisInvoicePrefix,DisNextInvoiceNo,UploadedBy,DisFreeIssuePrefix,DisFOCPrefix,ReceiptPrefix

strValues = "WAT2 "," ","","1","20","1","1","1","15","1","Jun 17 2011 6:33PM","1","HEMA","20110708 ","OR4 ","3"," ","RT4 ","TEM4","10","1","1","IN4 ","2","37"," ","PS4","1","20","41","1"," "," ","1"," ","1","1","1"," ","1","WAT2"," "," ","RP4 "

Please Help me this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: what is the values of these 2 strings: `strToFields` and `strValues` ... They are wrong

Comment: update in the code. I mention strToFields ,strValues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put all column values like  `initialValues.put(strToFields,strValues);`
what you wrote gives only the value for a column.you have other column in the table.Pls put them like this

```
int totalColumn=50;
String columName[]=new String[totalColumn];
//dynamically generating columnName;
String values[]=new String[totalColumn];
```

//dynamically generating values

```
for(int i=0;i<totalColumn;i++)
 initialValues.put(columnName[i],values[i]);`
```

Comment: Please I couldn't get it.Please tell me what I want to do it.

Comment: initialValues.put is putting the value for a column.In your case You are putting the value for only one column.But you have to put for ExecutiveCode,FreeIssuePrefix,DisPaySchedulePrefix,NextFreeIssueNo,NextReturnNo,UploadedType,DisNextFreeIssueNo,DisNextFOCNo,NextVisitNo,DisNextOrderNo,UploadedOn,NextReturnAcceptNo,BusinessUnit,TXNReferencePrefix,OrderPrefix,UploadedMethod,FOCPrefix,ReturnPrefix,RetailerPrefix,NextRetailerNo,NextInvoiceNo,NextGRNNo,InvoicePrefix,NextTXNReference,NextOrderNo,ReturnAcceptPrefix,PaySchedulePrefix,NextReceiptNo,NextFOCNo,NextPayScheduleNo,NextGRONo,.........

Comment: strToFields is only a string.So it can be used for only one column

Comment: Yes.Please tell me How I want to give. This is my strToFields = ExecutiveCode,FreeIssuePrefix,DisPaySchedulePrefix and strValues = "sss","sss","sss","sss","sss".... something like this ..

Comment: Its dynamically creating.I dont know this fields value & values.Runtime only it knows

Comment: but you have the column name in an array or in any kind of data structure.right?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you must do it

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put("ExecutiveCode","WAT2 ");
initialValues.put("FreeIssuePrefix"," ");
initialValues.put("DisPaySchedulePrefix","");
initialValues.put("NextFreeIssueNo","1");
initialValues.put("NextReturnNo","20");
initialValues.put("UploadedType","1");
//AND SO ON
```

Each value must be put into the ContentValues alone